# setTimeout function not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to integrate `setTimeout` function with a loop. I want to execute iterations with particular delay.Since there is no `sleep` function in JavaScript, I have to use `setTimeout`. But in the code sample I have shared , it's not working as expected.I want to display 2000, 4000, 6000 with the interval of 2 seconds.Please guide.

```js
function timedText() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txt");
    for(var i=2000;i<=6000;i=i+2000)
    {
    setTimeout(function(){ x.value=i; }, i);
    }

}
```

```html
<p>Click on the button below. The input field will tell you when two, four, and six seconds have passed.</p>

<button onclick="timedText()">Display timed text</button>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Comment: Would you not be better off using `setInterval` and `clearInterval`?

Answer (score 0):

simply try with [`setInterval()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH8L3I0MbTAhWKto8KHco_AA8QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_setinterval.asp&usg=AFQjCNGeKpvctZ0QksL4ryyHO0FVnU6BXw&sig2=5Jl9dIv_hWe76pwNPDLulg) .after use certain state of `6000` [`clearInterval()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiG--3V0MbTAhXGvY8KHareCQ0QFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_clearinterval.asp&usg=AFQjCNF5eXwLMatq9WhSrIXd736olamy2g&sig2=2gb2ApJiJxiPJKijRdvNlQ)

```js
function timedText() {
   var x = document.getElementById("txt");
   var time=2000;
   var timer = setInterval(function(){
   x.value =time;
     time +=2000;
     if(time > 6000){
     clearTimeout(timer)
     }
   },time)

}
```

```html
<p>Click on the button below. The input field will tell you when two, four, and six seconds have passed.</p>

<button onclick="timedText()">Display timed text</button>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```